# Making histogram of frequency of words

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I have successfully created a histogram of frequencies of numbers. I'd like to do the same with words.

```
bins = [1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,2,2,3,3,1,23,54,6,6,7,6,5,4]

@svg = d3
  .select('.histogram')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', @model.get('width'))
  .attr('height', @model.get('height'))
  .append('g')
data = d3
  .layout
  .histogram().bins(bins.length)(bins)
bar = @svg
  .selectAll('.bar')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
bar
  .append('rect')
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', (d) -> return d.x*5)
  .attr("width", (d) -> return d.y * 20)
  .attr("height", 5)
  .attr('fill','steel')
```

I'd like to build a histogram of frequencies for an array like this -

```
    bins = ['hello','hello','goodbye','goodbye','beatles','kill','harry','harry']
```

how do I go about doing that? It seems like using the histogram layout's value function would be a good bet, but that implies I need to maintain state somehow. Also, I'd like it so that the word appears as a label next to its associated bar.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried passing the array of words to the histogram layout?

Comment: yeah I have - that's what bins is

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you should you layout.histogram for the categorical data, as the idea of this layout is to distribute the values into bins, while in your case you just have a separate bar for each word.

So consider this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XmYDr/1/).

Here I manually calculate the distribution:

```
// calculate frequency for each word in the list
var groups = _(values).chain()
    .groupBy(_.identity)
    .map(function (values, key) {
        return {
            freq: values.length,
            value: key
        };
    })
    .sortBy(function (d) { return d.value; })
    .value();
```

And then draw a simple bar chart off this groups:

```
var bars = svg.selectAll('.bar')
    .data(groups)
    .enter().append('g');

bars
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x', 0)
    .attr('y', function (d, i) { return yScale(i); })
    .attr("width", function (d) { return xScale(d.freq); })
    .attr("height", barHeight)
    .attr('fill','steel');
```